# nginx rewrite rules to php files open a download dialog box?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I have a nginx server with work with php by fast cgi. when I use a rewrite like this:

```
rewrite "^/tested\.html" /index.html last;
```

everything is ok, and page index.html shown for tested.html, but when my target is a php file like this:

```
rewrite "^/tested\.html" /index.php last;
```

a download dialogbox is opened and when I save the file, I saw it contain my php codes!!!
anyone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NginX does not know how to execute PHP code, so instead your browser will just be given a text file with PHP in it.

Similarly to Apache where you need to install a module for PHP, on NginX, you need to install something like [PHP FPM](http://php-fpm.org/)